# How to convert Sys.Date in R from UTC to GMT

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

How do I convert the `Sys.Date()` from UTC to `GMT +2:00` in R. I have tried the below-mentioned code but it is not working.

```
Today_Date<-Sys.Date(TZ,'GMT +2:00')
```

Comment: are you trying to read/modify data you already have or is your `Sys.timezone()` incorrect?

Comment: ‘Sys.Date’ returns the current day in the current time zone. No UTC. No Time. So it's actually impossible to convert it to Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use lubridate for date work in R

```
td <- ymd( Sys.Date(), tz = "GMT" )
```

Would this suffice?

Comment: and you're getting midnight of said date of course, dates don't really have timezones as the others have pointed out

Answer (score 1):

While `Date` objects don't technically have timezones, they can be influenced by it depending on the use (e.g., fractional dates, or converting to/from `POSIXt` objects).

To answer the literal question of finding the correctly-formatted TZ string, use `OlsonNames()`:

```r
grep("GMT", OlsonNames(), value = TRUE)
#  [1] "Etc/GMT"    "Etc/GMT-0"  "Etc/GMT-1"  "Etc/GMT-10" "Etc/GMT-11"
#  [6] "Etc/GMT-12" "Etc/GMT-13" "Etc/GMT-14" "Etc/GMT-2"  "Etc/GMT-3" 
# [11] "Etc/GMT-4"  "Etc/GMT-5"  "Etc/GMT-6"  "Etc/GMT-7"  "Etc/GMT-8" 
# [16] "Etc/GMT-9"  "Etc/GMT+0"  "Etc/GMT+1"  "Etc/GMT+10" "Etc/GMT+11"
# [21] "Etc/GMT+12" "Etc/GMT+2"  "Etc/GMT+3"  "Etc/GMT+4"  "Etc/GMT+5" 
# [26] "Etc/GMT+6"  "Etc/GMT+7"  "Etc/GMT+8"  "Etc/GMT+9"  "Etc/GMT0"  
# [31] "GMT"        "GMT-0"      "GMT+0"      "GMT0"
```

I generally recommend against the `GMT/` variants, since they tend to ignore DST, though perhaps that's what you want.